# Parameter in the Like clause of the criteria in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am looking to create a query in MS Access that searches by a name provided by the user. However, I would like to let the user enter only the beginning of the name. So, I would imagine a search criteria like this:

```
Like "[Enter name: ]*"
```

How do I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put parameter into quotes - so it become just part of string.

```sql
Like [Enter name: ] & "*"
```